# html link breaks

Tags: html, hyperlink

i have the code below

```
<a id="treeSelector" style="cursor:pointer" >
    <img src="../../graphics/tree.gif" align="left" style="padding-right:5px;"/>
    <span>Root Page</span>
    <img src="../../graphics/arrow_down.gif" align="absmiddle"/>
</a>
```

My Problem is that using the span inside when mouseover the cursor form pointer becomes default arrow moving from arrow_down.gif to Root Pag text.

I know that if i use dislpay:block on  will solve my problem BUT this not what i want because link has onmouseover show another div.

Can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you try and make the question clearer?

Comment: Please don't put it all in a single line. Horizontally scrolling is heartattacking to programmers. Split after ~100 characters.

Comment: Could you rephrase this question again. It's a tad confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 really easy solutions.

1. Use HREF

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="return false;">...</a>
   ```
2. Use CSS

   ```
   #treeSelector, #treeSelector *{ cursor:pointer }
   ```

Comment: I think the first point is key here. In IE, at least, anchors don't seem to act like anchors (pointer style, for example) unless it actually has a href. Adding a href will fix it for IE, and I suspect that other browsers work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;">
```